# Google Container Engine: assign static IP to nodes for outbound traffic

Tags: gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine

I am using Google Container Engine to launch a cluster that connects to remote services (in a different data center / provider). The containers that are connecting may not have a kubernetes `service` associated with them and don't need external *in-bound* ip addresses. However, I want to set up firewall rules on the remote machines and have a known subnet that the nodes will be within when I expand/reduce the cluster or if a node goes down and is re-built.

In looking at Google Networks they appear to be related to *internal* networks (e.g. 10.128.0.0, etc). The external IP lets me set up single static IP addresses but not a range and I don't see how to apply that to a node — applying to a load balancer won't change the outbound IP address.

Is there a way I can reserve a block of IP addresses for my cluster to use in my firewall rules on my remote servers? Or is there some other solution I'm missing for this kind of thing?

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper solution for this is to use a VPN to connect the two networks. Google [Cloud VPN](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpn/overview) allows you to create this on the Google side.